# Good TCP/IP networking book for a programmer?

Tags: networking, tcp

Every day I write Web applications, and I have a good understanding of HTTP. However I want to close the gaps in my knowlege of network architecture. I'm not a sysadmin, so a hard-core sysadmin reference book would probably be a bit much for me, but I'm also not looking for a book on how to write code in any way -- I'm interested in the mechanisms underneath all that fun Web code I write.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I'd love to see more suggestions, please keep on answering guys!!

Comment: Just learned about a book from O'Reilly that seems perfect for the purpose: http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Browser-Networking-performance/dp/1449344763

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols**](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) by W. Richard Stevens is ***the book*** you want to read.

Comment: Great book but too long for a web applications programmer -1

Comment: Oh, you are so wrong ...

Answer (score 4):

[http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469)

Answer (score 0):

Also by the great W. Richard Stevens is Unix Network Programming (http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Networking-Sockets/dp/013490012X).