# Realtime TCP/IP stack

Tags: c++, c, real-time

I want to program (as efficiently as possible) a TCP/IP communication stack in C or C++. It really must run as fast as possible.

Does anyone have a good example or suggestion of where to start?

Comment: Loosely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562702/best-current-book-on-windows-networking-tcp-ip-sockets-packet-filtering-firew, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402515/good-tcp-ip-networking-book-for-a-programmer, any other questions you can find recommending books. "As fast as possible" isn't really consistent with anything less than a few years experience low-level network optimization, so reading a few books is a minimal effort. Then once you're really familiar, start reading books about actually *implementing* network stacks rather than just using them.

Comment: What's your criteria for 'fast'? Minimum latency on average? Guaranteed maximum latency? Maximum throughput?

Comment: Read "TCP/IP Illustrated" by late Rich Stevens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steve points out in the comments you do need quite a bit of experience to do this well.  So rather than jumping directly to your end goal I recommend these possible steps:

1. Write a reliable transport using UDP as a normal user-land protocol.
2. Write a custom protocol using raw sockets in user-land.
3. Write a kernel level protocol module/driver
4. Write your stack on a FPGA network card

Linux is a good option as the details you need are easily accessible and documented.

And oh yeah, stop as soon as you realize you won't likely outperform the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 6):

This is not meant as an insult, the guys who have developed the stacks for the well established operating systems have been doing this for years. This is what they do, unless you are in the business, I suggest you look at a different approach.

Different approach being, pick a stack that has decent performance (I hear that the latest tcp/ip stack in Solaris is nifty), then tune the hell out of it (there are lots of different flags and settings you can tune). If that fails to meet your needs, consider hardware solutions such as tcp offloading etc.

Writing your own stack, means you have to be confident enough to know that you can beat maybe 1000s of man years worth of effort in this field.

If this is for self development and learning, I suggest something simple like the source code for minix, it may have a simple to understand stack.

m2c.

Answer (score 3):

This is a huge task. I would recommend the [Contiki](http://www.sics.se/contiki/publications-and-documentation.html) operating system as a possible starting point. It has a TCP/IP stack.

Comment: hmm, lot's of OS's have tcp stacks, some are better than others! ;)

Comment: @Nim: sure, but Contiki has at least some relevant properties for real-time work, and is small, up-to-date and open-source.

Comment: @Steve, my comment was just nitpicking on @unwind's last statement! Not related to whether Contiki is a good starting point or not... :)

Answer (score 1):

[This may be worth looking at:](http://www.df.lth.se/~pkj/thesis_report/)

> [Implementing a High Performance Object Oriented TCP/IP Protocol Stack](http://www.df.lth.se/~pkj/thesis_report/)
>
> [Thesis for the Degree of Master of Science  Peter Kjellerstedt and
>   Henrik Baard](http://www.df.lth.se/~pkj/thesis_report/)

Answer (score 0):

**lwip** - A Lightweight TCPIP stack it's best to start learning about TCP/IP Stack

> git clone git://git.savannah.nongnu.org/lwip.git